# How to prevent apps from running in the background using battery saver

Tags: apps, battery-saver

I know that in order to prevent  apps from running in the background you just have to turn off it in battery saver. like this

[image]

But i am facing some unusual problems in some apps. I use regularly NEWS and MONEY app from Microsoft; even after turning off "Allow app to run in the background" for these apps in battery saver it will turn back on automatically after starting the app. Do you have any idea how to prevent it.

Answer (score 4):

So I was able to reproduce the issue you are describing using Microsoft's News app. Even when I disallowed background tasks in the battery saver it switched back to "Allow app to run in the Background" after using the app, specifically after going to the settings menu in the app.

The reason for this is that in the settings "Services" and "live tiles" are activated which require background tasks to function - so this will overwrite your battery saver settings. Turn these off and background tasks settings should stay on "disallow".

Microsoft actually requires app developers to provide you with these kind of options to disable background tasks. So I assume the same thing will work with the Money app.

Comment: it is not working for me. i have disabled all services in the Microsoft apps but still its reenabling after opening apps